# Javascript submit when selected issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

With the following `javascript` I'm trying to submit a result once it is selected, but nothing happens! Any ideas why this is happening?

```
<input name="search" id="search" class="search-query search_size" placeholder="Enter keyword to search" data-autocomplete-label="Sorry, nothing found." data-autocomplete="/items/autocomplete_item_title" type="search">

<script>
$('#search').bind('railsAutocomplete.select', function(event, data){
    $('#search').submit();
    alert(data.item.id);
});
</script>
```

**Update 1**

This is the rails form I'm trying to submit:

```
<%= form_tag items_path, :method => "get", id: "search" do %>
   <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: "search-query search_size",
                               placeholder: "Enter keyword to search", type: "search",
                               :"data-autocomplete-label" => "Sorry, nothing found.",
                               data: {autocomplete: autocomplete_item_title_items_path } %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil, :style => "display: none;" %>
<%end%>
```

Comment: What do you actually want the submit action to do? Post data to an specific page?

Comment: @TIm... it's a basic search form in rails. I would like to select the autocomplete result and once selected automatically submit it! hope this helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run `submit` function only on `form` element or on `input[type="submit"]`. That's why nothing happen.

> It can only be attached to  elements. Forms can be submitted either by clicking an explicit , , or , or by pressing Enter when certain form elements have focus.

<sub>https://api.jquery.com/submit/#entry-longdesc</sub>

on `form`:

```js
function submit(event) {
  alert('form submitted');
  e.preventDefault();
}

$('#form').submit(() => {
  console.log('form submitted');
  return false;
});

$('#form').submit();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

on `input`:

```js
function submit(event) {
  alert('form submitted');
  e.preventDefault();
}

$('#form').submit(() => {
  console.log('form submitted');
  return false;
});

$('button').submit();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @Mosh Feu! Is there a way around this? I would like to submit for search when a autocomplete result is selected!

Comment: Do you have a `form` that the `input` inside it?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, the `form` and the `input` have the same id `search` right?

Comment: Replace one of them. `id` attribute must be unique. Once you change it, you can call `submit` to the `form` element. Just note that it will refresh the page unless the `form` has handler that prevent the refresh and send the data with ajax, like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1960245/863110) answer.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Mosh Feu... I have already tried this, the one id was search and the form id was search-form, but nothing happened again! Not sure what wrong here! Kind of a newbie here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159401/discussion-between-mosh-feu-and-theopap).

Comment: Have you succeed?